# Bootstrap certain resources, such as mail fails

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

**Initial Problem**
    protected function _initMail()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('mail');
    }
in my Bootstrap.php
Fails with a:

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message
>   'Circular resource dependency detected'

**Solution:** Don't call a Ressource within its own bootstrap method (e.g. mail => _initMail).

**The Question:** *How to simplify setting up resources in the config to have less config code in the controller?*

So far I get $bootstrap->getResource('mail') to return something that looks like a bit like what I tried to achieve.
It returns an instance of Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail (nearly emtpy, without any attributes set).
The goal would be to have Zend_Mail::'s static properties to be set to the values defined in the config

This seems to be a general question about how to ACTUALLY bootstrap Zend resources, since no where is properly documentad how to bootstrap certain resources.
I simply followed the standard (and bootstrap view example).

My application.ini seems to be configured to handle the information needed for Mail configuration:

```
resources.view[] = 
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZSC_"
wall.upload = APPLICATION_PATH "/uploads"
wall.uploadTemporary = APPLICATION_PATH "/temp"

resources.mail.transport.type = sendmail
;resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp.udag.de"
;resources.mail.transport.auth = login
;resources.mail.transport.username = nix
;resources.mail.transport.password = nix
resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default

resources.mail.defaultFrom.email = "support@conexco.de"
resources.mail.defaultFrom.name = "Mr Conexco Support"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `$this->bootstrap('mail');` is calling the `_initMail()` method. So, you have a method calling itself infinitely, that's why you are getting the "Circular resource dependency" error message.

The calls to the `_initXXX()` methods are already handled by `$application->bootstrap()` in your `index.php` file, you only need to use them explicitly if you have dependencies between methods (i.e., mail depending on something else).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Try with `$this->getPluginResource('mail')`, I use this one instead.

Comment: You could also just call the method something else, that way you can call `$this->bootstrap('mail')` without introducing a loop.

Comment: Well, maybe my fault was to possibly override the "real" _initMail method.
I ll try to put the $this->bootstrap('mail') outside of the _initMail method and rename _initMail to something else